# I always have trouble laning Veigar against Morgana, are there any tips or tricks that could help me with this lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am picking up Veigar as my new main champion and have played him in over 100 games in the past week. I am doing very well in the majority of my games and there has only been one champion that I have a negative "lane win/loss" rate against, which is Morgana. I have been keeping track over "lane win/loss" score based on how well I think I did during laning against my opponent, though it is slightly biased. When I win or go even, I count it as a win and if I lose I count it as a loss.

Anyway, back to the main question. How can you play Veigar against Morgana and win? I have been able to go even/win four times and have lost six times. The two I went even with, there were outside factors like jungle ganks and lack of skill of the Morgana that I was up against. I have watched replays of Nyjacky playing this matchup and doing extremely well. The only problem that I have with doing what he does is just, he is much better than me. I cannot just imitate his every move, so I was not able to just absorb all of the information I need from simply watching him.

Are there any tips or tricks I could use to improve my quality of life laning against Morgana as Veigar? I appreciate any responses that you guys are able to give me.

EDIT: I love all the response this is getting, but further opinions would be appreciated. I have yet to queue against a Morgana since, so I still have some time to think and theorycraft if anyone is up to helping, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As for a Veigar vs. Morgana lane. You, as the Veigar, should never even attempt to harass her. Farm farm farm. Level your Q to three or so for effective lasthitting, and after that W for effective Counterpushing against Morgana. Hope for a better lategame, as If you've farmed well enough, you can crap on her with your burst. Also, focus in the early-midgame on heavy lane ganking, as your stun is one of the longest in the game.

Comment: I love this answer. It addressed something that few of the other people missed when answering; that being the ability of Morgana to just push me to death and disable my ability to roam. Thank you.

Comment: I disagree with the idea of not harassing her.  Veigar can really out-damage Morgana especially early on.  Level up your Q to 5 first and harass with it and auto attacks and you can often zone her out of experience.  Morgana is a beast late-game too, so if you let her farm without any trouble she will be way ahead of you in terms of CS and might impact the game more than you.

Answer (score 2):

I play Veigar as my main champ and I love laning against Morgana.  I agree with a lot of what has been said already but at first glance some of it seems contradictory (you need to farm but you also should harass).

Early game Veigar should be able to trade much better than Morgana if you can dodge her skill shot (movement speed quints! and early lvl 2 boots).  If you can successfully do this then you can sometimes zone her out or force her to back early which can get you an early CS advantage.  If you watch Nyjacky he definitely does this (see video below).  If you can constantly keep Morgana low and out-trade her you have a good chance of getting a kill once you hit level 6 because you bait out her shield with E and then just Q, R, Ignite once its down.

Now come mid-game the trouble is that she can push the lane hard even if she is behind.  So here leveling up your W so that you can push just as hard can be very helpful.  Again you can still harass with your Q which might force her to use her Spellshield leaving her open to your combo afterwards.  You also need to be aware of who on the enemy team has tenacity boots which might then make leveling E up to 3 or 4 first a priority.

And never underestimate the power of auto-attacking as part of your harass (again just watch nyjacky in the video)

The other thing that can mis-lead Veigar players is his Q passive (farming up AP with last hits).  If you don't harass with Q and you get pushed up to your tower constantly you will lose your lane and it doesn't matter how much AP you get from your Q.  Playing passively and not harassing will lead to losing your lane more often than not.

[Here is a video of Crs Nyjacky playing Veigar vs Morgana](http://youtu.be/nEEkahlJzoA)

I think one thing that is striking about Nyjacky's play is how much he uses his Q to harass early on.  I know you can't mimic his play move for move, but if you pay attention to his general strategy you can start to practice that.

Comment: +1. The early game harass is far more important than the 10-20 extra AP you'd get from throwing your Q on minions. If your Q harass can force her out of lane once, you've more than made up for the lack of AP.

Answer (score 1):

No one wins against Morgana, it's just a farm lane, since she will spellshield stuff you throw at her and she sits back while her pool farms for her, so it's really hard to win versus her as any AP mids, but what you can do is bait her to use her shield then you can pretty much do whatever you want to against her for about 15 seconds.

But just farm more then her and try to secure kills in other lanes and make moves toward obectives, thats how you truly win versus Morgana ( and any other mid).

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer not only helps with Veigar vs Morgana, but all matchups. :D

Comment: QFT. Morgana is probably the strongest lane champ in the game.

Answer (score 1):

With Morgana's black shield, your best bet is just to harass her down with Q's.

If she wants to prevent harass, she'll use her black shield which takes a HUGE chunk of her mana.

Learn the cool-down of her black shield, your best bet is to pretend to go in on her, force her to black shield, then come back before her shield is back up.

Comment: Thank you for this response. It slightly contrasts what some others have been saying, but I do feel that this may work sometimes depending on the Morgana player and their level of aggressiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you've probably discovered the key to veigar is using the stun to land W and then popping other skills as necessary. Because Morgana's black shield blocks crowd control, it's tricky to hit your W and therefore you lose significant damage.
Try to do fake aggressive plays so she wastes shield and then go in for a combo. - When doing this ALWAYS have wards or the enemy jungler will take advantage.
If you're struggling to kill her - roam and see what you can pick up on other lanes.

However, Morgana was kindof designed vs champs like Veigar so you're going to have a hard time. Just because someone like nyjacky did really well doesn't mean that's a favourable lane.
Take Froggen. The guy plays the best anivia in the world (after MacLaren :D), and will win his lane 99% of the time. This does not mean that if you play anivia you will win all matchups.

With that said, I don't mean to sound negative. As you play more Morgana's you'll start getting used to her and will eventually win most games.
Best of luck,
Raf

Comment: Don't forget to go for minion last hits with Q! It makes for a useful boost to AP.

Comment: Yes, against Morgana I feel you must farm with Q in order to either farm under tower or to counter he constant pushing when I don't have blue/levels into my skills because she just simply outpushes my and denies farm due to tower.

Answer (score 0):

These guys are right morgana forces you into a farm lane, as shes pretty safe and you can't push and roam as she can push the lane back fast.

Key to beating her is mobility imo, champs like ahri, vlad, fizz can evade her ult and retaliate well.

Unfortunately for you veigar is not the best pick vs her as she black shield shuts you down  hard

Comment: Thank you for your input, but giving other champions that do well as suggestions doesn't really help as far as answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't play aggressive at all.
Farm your Q and become an endgame monster. If you try to engage her she black shields your stun and lands full combo on you, while you do nothing. If your jungle ganks mid make sure you pop her spell shield then drop your stun. Otherwise you've wasted a strong CC Spell. Endgame once you've farmed your Q so much she will get instatly bursted before she can even ult. Good Luck.